# Cannot use php in any other files

Tags: php

So I have two php classes, one is a class, one uses the other, my class is:

(menu.php)

```
 <?php
public class Menu
{
        $home = '<li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>';
        $home_selected = '<li class="navhome"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></li>';

        $projects = '<li><a href=""><span>Projects</span></a></li>';
        $projects_selected = '<li class="navhome"><a href=""><span>Projects</span></a></li>';

        $contact = '<li><a href=""><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>';
        $contact_selected = '<li class="navhome"><a href=""><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>';

        public function getMyMenu($value)
        {
                switch($value) {
                        case "home":
                                return (string) $home_selected . $projects . $contact;
                                break;
                        case "projects":
                                return $home . $projects_selected . $contact;
                                break;
                        case "contact":
                                return $home . $projects . $contact_selected;
                                break;
                }
        }

}
?>
```

however, in index.php, where ever

```
<?php include("menu.php"); 
      $menu = new Menu();
      echo($menu->getMyMenu("home")); ?>
```

or any variation of this is put, the web page just wont load after that, for example if it is put in the middle of the page, the end of the page isn't even sent to the browser.

I'm very new to php, and I'm hoping this is a "duh" answer, if you need more please ask; thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should quote (`'` or `"`) the string

```
$home = '<li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>';
```

full code:

```
class Menu
{
    private $home = '<li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>';
    private $home_selected = '<li class="navhome"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></li>';

    private $projects = '<li><a href=""><span>Projects</span></a></li>';
    private $projects_selected = '<li class="navhome"><a href=""><span>Projects</span></a></li>';

    private $contact = '<li><a href=""><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>';
    private $contact_selected = '<li class="navhome"><a href=""><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>';

    public function getMyMenu($value)
    {
        switch($value) {
            case "home":
                return $this->home_selected . $this->projects . $this->contact;
                break;
            case "projects":
                return $this->home . $this->projects_selected . $this->contact;
                break;
            case "contact":
                return $this->home . $this->projects . $this->contact_selected;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stupid mistake, I am just using vi so I completely missed this, for some reason on this computer syntax highlighting isn't working

Comment: updated the code again, if you want to use member variables, you should use `$this->home` instead of `$home`

Comment: class variables, such as your `$home`, `$projects`, `$contact`. if you just say `$home` in `getMyMenu()`, it refers to the variable you created within the function, but there's none, so nothing displayed. if you need to use class variables, you have to say `$this->yourVariable`.

Answer (score 3):

Your strings aren't quoted. You need to use `'string'` for strings which doesn't contain variables, and `"string $var"` if you vant to add variables values to your strings.

Also, very helpfull is write in the begining of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This enables full error tracking, so PHP tells you which problems on which string he see - realy very helpfull!

Also, look at your string:

```
return "hello world";
```

How will the switch bellow this instruction works, if function will stops befor it on this string? If you want this return as default, you should place it AFTER your switch.

Comment: I had already edited that line out of my post, that was put in there on accident when moving into stackoverflow, I'm not sure how that even made it in there.

Comment: Error reporting will be shown right in browser, on the page you are debugging

Comment: It should be noted though that `error_reporting(E_ALL)` should only be added for while you are building the site, and once you actually put it live to the world, you should probably turn this off (remove it). You might also benefit from doing a few PHP tutorials before you go too much further, otherwise there's a good chance you'll end up releasing something that looks like it works, but actually puts your server and your passwords at risk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the visibility of the class properties, for example:

```
class Menu {
    public $home = ...;
}
```

Also note that you should not have `public` before the keyword `class`. Also you are missing quotes around all of your string property values. Basically everything is wrong and you most likely have `show_errors` disabled.

Comment: Look at my unswer (updated) - there I writed code for error handling enabling.

Comment: I dont want $home to be public, the only thing that needs to see what $home is is getMyMenu function